# logger.catch c аргументами

Tags: python, логирование

Я использую loguru для ведения логов. Можно ли при использовании `@logger.catch()` указать еще какие-либо аргументы?

Есть логер и функция в которую сыпятся сообщения

```
def func(error_message):
    ...
logger.add(func, catch=True)
```

И есть функция с декоратором генерирующая ошибку

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
@logger.catch()
def start(message):
    message.text / 2
```

При отлове ошибки, весь трейс я получаю в параметре `error_message` у `func`, можно как-то еще туда что-либо прокинуть? `id пользователя` скажем

Comment: `@logger.catch()` это из `loguru`?

Comment: @gil9red Да, забыл упомянуть в вопросе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То что я искал - это [loger.bind](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/logger.html#loguru._logger.Logger.bind)

```
def error_caught(message):
    result = loads(message)
    bot.send_message(...)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def main_func(message: Message):
    with my_loger.bind(user_id=message.from_user.id).catch():
        message.text / 2


my_loger.configure(extra={"user_id": "", })
my_loger.add(error_caught, format='{message}-{extra[user_id]}', serialize=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

В качестве альтернативы могу предложить логгер [Polog](https://github.com/pomponchik/polog). Там все варианты сбора логов (обычный вызов функции, декоратор, контекстный менеджер) работают через одну и ту же [функцию](https://github.com/pomponchik/polog#log---%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8). Давайте покажу, как это работает в случае [контекстного менеджера](https://github.com/pomponchik/polog/tree/develop#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80).

Начнем с установки библиотеки:

```
$ pip install polog
```

Предварительно импортируем все необходимое и зарегистрируем обработчик, который будет записывать все логи в консоль:

```
from polog import log, config, file_writer

config.add_handlers(file_writer())
```

Перейдем к нашей теме: логирующий контекстный менеджер. Базовый случай применения выглядит вот так:

```
with log("my message"):
    ...
```

В данной конфигурации происходящее внутри блока кода будет записано. Результат в консоли будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
[2022-10-31 23:55:10.023636] |    1    | SUCCESS | MANUAL | "my message" | where: ? | time of work: 0.00001097 sec.
```

Также вы можете передать сюда какие-то дополнительные аргументы, они тоже запишутся:

```
with log("my message", lol="kek"):
    ...
```

Результат:

```
[2022-10-31 23:57:24.215530] |    1    | SUCCESS | MANUAL | "my message" | where: ? | time of work: 0.00001192 sec. | lol: "kek"
```

Еще одна крутая возможность, можно редактировать записываемый лог прямо изнутри блока кода, который он записывает:

```
with log("my message", lol="kek") as context:
    context("the new message!", kek="lol")
```

Результат:

```
[2022-10-31 23:59:13.732950] |    1    | SUCCESS | MANUAL | "the new message!" | where: ? | time of work: 0.00001836 sec. | lol: "kek" | kek: "lol"
```

И последняя фича, вы можете улавливать исключения в данном блоке кода:

```
with log("my message", lol="kek").suppress() as context:
    context("the new message!", kek="lol")
    raise ValueError
```

Результат:

```
[2022-11-01 00:01:39.383987] |    2    |  ERROR  | MANUAL | "the new message!" | where: ? | time of work: 0.00037789 sec. | exception: ValueError("") | traceback: raise ValueError (".../some_file.py", line 7, in <module>) | lol: "kek" | kek: "lol"
```

Подробнее читайте в документации к библиотеке по ссылкам выше.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! вместо отправки одного и того же ответа на несколько вопросов лучше было оставлять в комментариях ссылку на первый из ответов. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос